# Spark job running fast after count

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I have a scala job which had few CDC records ( 10K records) and as part of a merge job, it does member matching ( 4 million) from other Hive table which has 4 million members , provider matching from other Hive table which has 1 million providers and a bunch of other stuff ( recycle logic/rejection logic) which usually takes around 30 min to complete.
With the same volume I have added action ( count(*)) after every module to understand which one takes more time, however after using action it got completed in 6 min. Usually as per best practices we should not use action frequently, however I don't understand what's making the job run fast ? any link with explanation would be helpful.

Is it that since the resource may have got released after every module execution due to action, it's making overall job run fast.

My cluster is 6 node with 13 cores machine and 64GB memory, however there are other processes also running ..so it's usually overutilized.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).